# create-react-class without npm using require and npm in React 16

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a stand alone react example without using webpack, npm, JSX or babel. As React.createClass has been removed in React v16, how can I make the following code work, without using require.js and npm:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>React Hello World</title>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var Greetings = React.createClass(
                {
                    render: function () {
                        return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Greetings, ' + this.props.name + '!');
                    }
                });
            ReactDOM.render(
                React.createElement(Greetings, { name: 'World' }),
                document.getElementById('root')
            );
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A UMD build of `create-react-class` can also be obtained from unpkg, as you're doing with the other libraries:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/create-react-class@15.6.2/create-react-class.min.js"></script>
```

You'll also need to replace any instances of `React.createClass` with `createReactClass`, as detailed [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.createclass).

That said, I'd give some thought to whether or not you actually need `create-react-class` - every major browser except for IE now supports ES6 classes, so  you don't really need Babel to use them any more.

Comment: sidenote that ie is not the only concern; older android tablets and phones are as well.